# How do I find the Probability Function of this Transform?

Tags: probability, transformation

Given the Probability Generating Function  for a non-negative, integer-valued, R.V. $X$ as:

$$
g_X(t)=\log\left(\frac 1 {1-qt}\right).
$$
How do I compute its Probability Function, $P(X=k)$? A step-by-step answer would be much appreciated.

The answer in the book is 
$$
P(X=k)=\frac {(1-e^{-1})^k} k.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function is defined by 
$$g_X(t)=\sum_k P(X=k)t^k.\tag1$$
Taking $t=1$ we have
$$\log\left(\frac1{1-q}\right)=g_X(1)=\sum_{k}P(X=k)=1$$
so we deduce that $-\log(1-q)=1$ and thus that $q=1-\mathrm e^{-1}$.
To conclude, write the Taylor expansion in $t$ of $g_X$
$$g_X(t)=\log\left(\frac1{1-qt}\right)=-\log(1-qt)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(qt)^k}k$$
by identification with (1), you get $P(X=k)=q^k/k$ as the answer says.

Comment: Thanks Tom-Tom! Also, does "by identification with (1)" mean something like, "using the result in equation (1)"?

Comment: We use the fact that the coefficients for $t^k$ with a given $k$ must be equal in (1) and in $g_X(t)$. In that case, these coefficients are $P(X=k)$ in (1) and $q^k/k$ in $g_X(t)$.

Comment: Very detailed, thanks!